# How do I fix this git push reject (pre-recieve hook declined)?

Tags: git, github

I created a new folder locally in my git repository, put some files in it, and went to push it to the repository on GitHub. When I first tried, it told me one of the files is larger than the maximum of 100 Mb, so I removed it and replaced it with two other files covering similar content. The largest file in the folder is now 31 Mb.

However, I keep getting the same error. I tried removing and then re-adding the folder in git. I tried `git reset HEAD foo/` to unstage all the files in the folder, and I deleted and then recreated the folder in the OS file system and then re-added it to git. Same error.

`git status` for my local repository returns `nothing to commit, directory clean`. But when I then try `git push`, as I suspected, it starts sending the data for a whole bunch of stuff. It takes it a good 10 minutes to finish, and then it tells me the same thing it has been all day - the push includes a file larger than the permitted size.

I know only enough git to function, this really isn't my area at all. How do I resolve this error?

Comment: can you reproduce this if you start fresh? clone the repo, copy the files, add, commit and push. If you can repro, can you provide a link to the repo and the commands you are running?

Comment: @Mircea Ok, let me try that. When i try `git pull` it tells me it is up to date, but clone is different, right?

Comment: @Mircea That worked, thanks :) I hadn't started fresh enough.

Comment: I suspect that if you'd `git reset --hard @{u}` in the original workspace, you would have been able to do it. I think you were just adding new commits on top of your original non-compliant one. You write what `git status` said about the working copy, but not how much ahead/behind it said you were. I suspect you were more ahead than you realized/understood.

Comment: @Mort yeah, that must be it. It said the local copy was several commits ahead. I thought it would only send the last commit. Because i know so little about it, i'm skittish about taking action that could result in lost data. It was comfortable for me to clone the whole thing over, because i had the old one to go back to if i messed it up.